# How to use REGEXP in SQLite3 to extract matched string (as a column value)

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

Is there a way to use REGEXP to return not just whether or not there was a match (i.e. `1` or `0`), but the actual match itself. For example, if I have a column of URLs and I want to extract the matched portion of a URL (e.g. the domain):

```
SELECT url REGEXP '\w+\.com' AS domain
FROM urls
GROUP by domain;
```

Not sure if there are differences between REGEXP extensions, but FWIW, I'm using the one found in [DB Browser for SQLite](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Regular-Expressions)

Comment: Does not this return matching part `SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url REGEXP '\w+\.com'` ?

Comment: @revo..that returns a row if the pattern matches,else it doesn't. The OP is asking for the pattern itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REGEXP operator returns just a boolean value, whether the text matches or not.

If you want to get more information, you have to write some other function.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as I haven't found any other (official) alternative, and the REGEXP operator is as you say. Thanks!