# SQLite: How to extract only numbers and special characters from column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to extract the numbers and the special characters in a string, how can I do that in SQL? (SQLite)

Is there a way with FORMAT()? with REPLACE()?
I search for the [@$!%*?&/] and the [0-9] numbers...

**String:**

```
Rue des cocotiers, 9/11
```

**Result:**

```
9/11
```

Thanks

Comment: Something like that is easier done in the program that's making the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would generally be a regex solution, but although sqlite now has the ability to run REGEXP expressions in WHERE clauses, it has not implemented the standard regexp_replace function found in more comprehensive SQL implementations.

[How to use REGEXP in SQLite3 to extract matched string (as a column value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107055/how-to-use-regexp-in-sqlite3-to-extract-matched-string-as-a-column-value)

To run an expression like this:

```sql
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(threeload.title, '\b([\d*#+\/]+)\b')) str
  FROM threeload
 WHERE threeload.title REGEXP '\b([\d*#+\/]+)\b';
```

you would first need to recompile sqlite with an additional function, perhaps like the one outlined in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586265/10890850

Here are the steps in case it gets deleted (not my answer, please give the original response any votes):

> Sqlite by default does not provide regex_replace function. You
>   need to load it as an extension. Here is how i managed to do it.
>
> [Download this C code for the extension (icu_replace)](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-regex-replace-ext)
>
> Compile it using
>
> ```
> gcc --shared -fPIC -I sqlite-autoconf-3071100 icu_replace.c -o icu_replace.so
> ```
>
> And in sqlite3 runn following command post above
>   mentioned command has run and create a file icu_replace.so
>
> ```
> SELECT load_extension(' path to icu_replace.so',
> 'sqlite3_extension_init') from dual;
> ```
>
> After this you will be able to use such a function as :-
>
> ```
> select regex_replace('\bThe\b',x,'M') from dual;
> ```